# adding sound to an OpenGL app

Tags: c++, audio

i am creating an OpenGL application and decided to look into adding sound...
what is the best sound(api?) i was thinking about using OpenAL but i had issues finding any good resources... 
if possible could you please provide tutorial/info of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one i used a while ago for 3D sound.

http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/

It is called IrrKlang, it has good documentation for the API and it really easy to integrate. You should be able to get sound playing within an hour or so of downloading it.

Comment: awesome...ill look into it thanks :D...does it cost money?? :O

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of people use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) for that, it provides portable creation of OpenGL contexts as well as sound support.

[Here's a tutorial.](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL_mixer%3aTutorials%3aPlaying_a_WAV_Sound_File)

Comment: As long as SDL provides 3D sound. I think the tutorial you linked doesn't cover 3D sound. And as he's developing a 3D application (if not, why OpenGL) and giving OpenAL as example, that's what he's probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAL is another choice, plus it resembles OpenGL:

http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx